# Trying to create a map showing route in WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, maps, gmap.net

I'm creating an app that imports a set of values from CSV, including a set of coordinates when measuring something. I created a list of objects from CSV file and I tried to create a list of extracted coordinates to create a route on map, so I tried finding ways from other people to how they created routes but nothing worked in my case

```
public partial class RouteWindow : Window
{
    private GMapControl gmapControl;

    public RouteWindow(List<BaseCsvData> list)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<(double Latitude, double Longitude)> coordinates = 
            list.Select(data => (data.Latitude, data.Longitude)).ToList();

        gmapControl = new GMapControl();

        gmapControl.Width = 800;
        gmapControl.Height = 460;

        // init
        gmapControl.MapProvider = GMapProviders.OpenStreetMap;
        GMaps.Instance.Mode = AccessMode.ServerOnly;
        gmapControl.MinZoom = 1;
        gmapControl.MaxZoom = 18;
        gmapControl.Zoom = 12;
        gmapControl.Position = new PointLatLng(coordinates[0].Latitude, coordinates[0].Longitude);

        // markers
        foreach (var (latitude, longitude) in coordinates)
        {
            GMapMarker marker = new GMapMarker(new PointLatLng(latitude, longitude));
            gmapControl.Markers.Add(marker);
        }

        // list of points
        List<PointLatLng> routePoints = coordinates.Select(c => new PointLatLng(c.Latitude, c.Longitude)).ToList();

        // add GMapControl to grid
        Grid grid = new Grid();
        grid.Children.Add(gmapControl);
        this.Content = grid;

        // zooming
        gmapControl.MouseWheel += GmapControl_MouseWheel;

        this.Closed += (sender, e) =>
        {
            DisposeMapControl();
        };
    }

    private void GmapControl_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;

        if (e.Delta > 0)
        {
            // Zoom in
            gmapControl.Zoom += 1;
        }
        else if (e.Delta < 0)
        {
            // Zoom out, with a minimum zoom level
            if (gmapControl.Zoom > 1)
            {
                gmapControl.Zoom -= 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public void DisposeMapControl()
    {
        gmapControl.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I tried code from some other online projects, some from WinForms, I tried asking ChatGPT for help but it returned

```
// Create a route
        GMapRoute route = new GMapRoute(routePoints, "Route");
        route.Stroke = new Pen(Brushes.Blue, 3).Frozen; // Set the color and thickness of the route line
        gmapControl.Overlays.Add(route);
```

To which were errors on Stroke 'GMapRoute' does not contain a definition for 'Stroke' and no accessible extension method 'Stroke' accepting a first argument of type 'GMapRoute' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) and same error for Overlays. I'm relatively new to C# and using some library for maps so I would be thankful for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

To add any object to map you can use `gmapControl.Markers.Add`. Even though it looks like you could add only `GMapMarker` objects, other objects also inherit from `GMapMarker` (in this case `GMapRoute`).

Changing visual style can be done via `GMapRoute.Shape` property.

```
GMapRoute route = new GMapRoute(routePoints);
route.Shape = new Path() { Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue), StrokeThickness = 3 };
gmapControl.Markers.Add(route);
```

You can style point markers in similar fashion:

```
// markers
foreach (var (latitude, longitude) in coordinates)
{
    GMapMarker marker = new GMapMarker(new PointLatLng(latitude, longitude));
    marker.Shape = new Ellipse() 
    { 
        Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),
        Width = 8,
        Height = 8,
        // Without Margin, circles would not be centered.
        Margin = new Thickness(-4, -4, 0, 0) 
    };

    gmapControl.Markers.Add(marker);
}
```